# Properly installing WiX Toolset 4.0.2

Tags: wix, wix4

I installed WiX 4.0.2 using
`dotnet tool install --global wix`

this installs WiX to
`%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools\.store\wix\4.0.2\wix\4.0.2\tools\net6.0\any`

inside this folder, there's no Wix*Extension.dll, no candle.exe, no light.exe

(candle.exe and light.exe are no where to be found on the PC in fact)

I can only build basic packages which call for no extensions

how do I install the FULL WiX Toolset with extensions included, and candle.exe / light.exe?

Comment: Candle & Light [and most of the 'old' WiX tools] are gone from WiX v4.x ... you should see Wix.exe on your system.
Have you tried downloading the nuget package?

Answer (score 2):

`candle.exe` and `light.exe` have been replaced with the single `wix build` command. That change (and many other v3 to v4 changes) are [documented on wixtoolset.org](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/fourthree/).

I also cover it in my very [first episode of the Deployment Dojo](https://youtube.com/live/-Y7dOtciOJw), if you want to see it in video form.